# Ruby select multiple elements from a .split

Tags: ruby, string, loops, parsing, split

String:

```
string = "this;is;a;string;yes"
```

I can split the string and append each element to an array like this

```
arr = []
string.split(";").each do |x|
  arr << x
end
```

Is there an easy way to take the first third and fourth values other than something like this.

```
x = 0 
string.split(";").each do |x|
  if x == 0 or x == 2 or x == 3 then arr << x end
  x += 1
end
```

Comment: Just pointing out some idioms. First example would be just `arr = string.split ";"` and second would use `string.split(";").each_with_index do |x, i|` rather than maintain your own index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Use [`Array#values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at):

```
string = "this;is;a;string;yes"
string.split(";").values_at(0, 2, 3)
# => ["this", "a", "string"]
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/FussyRecursiveSpools